# ignore chars between 2 chars

Tags: c

Im looking through a file. if I run into a '#' I want to ignore everything until I get to '\n'
. my current logic is not working.

Im trying to strip comments from the file
I think the problem has something to do with my logic in the second while loop

```
int wishforint(FILE *in)
{
char c;
int d;
int i=0;
int smarr[5];

while(i<5)
{
   fscanf(in, "%c", &c);
   printf("c is %c\n",c);

   if(isdigit(c))
   {
      ungetc(c, in);
      fscanf(in, "%d", &d);
/*add this later. 
return d;
*/
      smarr[i]=d;
      printf("smarr[%d]= %d\n",i,d);
      i++;
   }
   else if(c=='#')
   {
      while(fscanf(in,"%c",&c) != EOF && c != '\n')
      {}
      break;
   }
}


   printf("Width is = %d\n", smarr[1]);
   printf("Height is= %d\n", smarr[2]);
   printf("Max value= %d\n", smarr[3]);

   return 7;
}
```

Comment: You are trying to strip comments from a source file yes? Also, please post all of the code. For example, where is 'i' declared?

Comment: yeah, I'm trying to strip comments. full code added

Answer (score 4):

'#' is not a digit, so you are probably hitting the `continue` before making it to the `else if`.

Answer (score 1):

Two problems with the code.

First fscanf does not check for EOF. Fix:

```
    //fscanf(in, "%c", &c);
    if (fscanf(in, "%c", &c) == EOF) { break; }
```

Secondly, there ought not to be a 'break' in the '#' clause:

```
    else if(c=='#')
    {
      while(fscanf(in,"%c",&c) != EOF && c != '\n')
      {}
      //break;
    }
```

Comment: if I take the break out, I get an infinite loop.

Comment: The break should be when you find EOF at the top of the loop with the first fscanf. I tested your code with the changes I made and it worked fine. The break is just in the wrong place. It needs to be with the first fscanf, not the third.

Answer (score 0):

May be usage of sscanf and fgets will be more easy?

Probably something like this:

```
while (fgets(buf, BUF_LENGTH, in) != NULL){
    errno=0;
    if ((sscanf(buf, "%d", &d) == 0) && (errno == 0)){
      //we have a comment
      continue;
    }else if(errno != 0){
      //error handling
    }
    //we have a value
    smarr[i]=d;
    i++;
}
```

It should works well with one-value-in-column file. Where comments starts from begin of new line or after value.

Can you show example of input data?